# First time adding a contact form to a static website (trying to use formspree)

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I did some looking around on here and found out about [formspree.io](https://formspree.io/) but I'm unsure how to set it up. My first question is, does my homepage need to be a ".html" extension or ".php" extension? Secondly do I need to test this in my xampp environment or will it work locally?

Here is my HTML form:

```
<section id="two" class="wrapper style2 special">
            <div class="inner narrow">
                <header>
                    <h2>Get in touch</h2>
                </header>
                <form class="grid-form" method="post" action="https://formspree.io/carsonclark2009@gmail.com">
                    <div class="form-control narrow">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input name="name" id="name" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control narrow">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input name="email" id="email" type="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="message">Message</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4" placeholder="Ask your question or set up an appointment here..."></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="actions">
                        <li><input value="Send Message" type="submit"></li>
                    </ul>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
```

I tried it and I got nothing sent to my email so I'm definitely doing something wrong but I'm not sure what. If I were to just do it myself would that require a lot of PHP code and how would I test it if my site is not on a server yet?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It's probably better to ask them yourself: team@formspree.io

Comment: Are you sending these emails from localhost? That might be problem.

Comment: Figured it out, it wasn't set up properly in localhost. 

Thanks

Comment: You can also try doing it with. www.enformed.io worked great to me.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! Formspree has been working pretty well for me though, so I'll probably just keep using that service.